# Angular - How to get JQuery object in Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, package.json

Refer the following code:-

```
protected get myModalDialogRef(): JQuery {
    return $('#myModalDialog');
}
```

what needs to be installed so that i can have a return type as JQuery?
In package.json, I could see ""@types/bootstrap": "^4.1.0",".
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This blog post might help. Refer this: 
https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-angular-cli-project-592e0fe63176

Answer (score 0):

You should install [jquery ts types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery) and make sure you add "jquery" in "types" array in `tsconfig.json`. Another solution would be to declare a global variable like this `declare var jQuery: any`. However, this would not give you the autocomplete you need.

Comment: You mean to say:-     "typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ] ?

Comment: Also the code from where I picked the shared code snippet, there is no reference to var jQuery? I am not able to understand.

Comment: @Sidd It turns out that you do not have to add anything to the typeRoots or types arrays. As per tsconfig docs: "By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation.".

As for the second approach that I have suggested I meant a typescript global variable declaration - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables